# Login required error when upload files to google drive using NodeJS (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am developing NodeJS API to upload multi-images to Google Driver, when user create an Ebook (include name, description and ebookPhoto), I am using ExpressJS to write Rest API. And using [multer-google-drive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-google-drive) it's a multer middleware Storage Engine for upload file to Google Drive.
I also follow this link [Upload images to Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870427/how-to-upload-images-to-google-drive-from-nodejs-api)
to upload file to Google Drive. Below is these steps that I did.

1- Step 1: I run follow code to to get "token.json" file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']; // This SCOPE is for upload file
const credentials = require('./credentials.json');
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

const getAccessToken = (oAuth2Client, resolve, reject) => {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return reject('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      resolve(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}
```

2- Step 2 I run below code to get authorization:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const credentials = require('./credentials.json')
const token = require('./token.json');


const authorize = () => {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    if (token && typeof token === 'object') {
      return oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
    }
    return null
}


var drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authorize});
```

3- Step 3 is step using multer-google-drive to upload files, I do like this:

```
// Upload lên storage của google
var gDriverUpload = multer({
    storage: GoogleDriveStorage({
      drive: drive,
      parents: 'id-parents', // this is id of folder in google drive
      fileName: function (req, file, cb) {
        let filename = `ebook-${file.originalname}`;
        cb(null, filename);
      }
    })
  })
```

And this is my route for API:

```
// Create and upload to google driver
EbookRouter.post('/gdriver', gDriverUpload.array('ebookPhoto', 5), ebookController.createEbook);
```

So when I call API like this to upload Ebook information (include ebookPhoto) I am get error name is: "Login required"

```
localhost:3009/api/ebook/gdriver
```

Detail error is below:

```
POST /api/ebook/gdriver 500 1478.509 ms - 354
Error: Login Required
    at Gaxios._request (E:\google_api_uploader\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:85:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Please help me to find out this problem.
Thanks you so much

Comment: I believe that is because you don't have yet your tokens in your working directory. When you create a simple node.js application to use Google Drive API you would need to have your credentials.json file in your working directory . Then, when you run your file, it will pass you in the console a link to open to do the Login and then generate the token file in your working directory that your application will be using for authorising its access to your Drive API.

Comment: Try looking if you are getting that login link in your console or try first to run this with plain node.js to get your token and then integrate it with express and the rest. Let me know if any of this has solved your issue.