# to download torrent files to google drive or mega drive

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any library for creating a backend torrent downloader like seedr.cc  (https://www.seedr.cc)
I need to host that nodejs app in Heroku and connect google drive to it. need a guide

Comment: Hi Nipun, welcome to our community. Your post doesn't really conform our standards as it's not really a development question. At the very least it is expected you add some information on what you've been trying to do and why it didn't work, so it's not as if your asking us to solve this one thing for you while you're putting in no effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webtorrent](https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent) to download the file into a nodejs server, Then you have to upload it to google drive using API. ref : [How to upload images to google drive from NodeJS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870427/how-to-upload-images-to-google-drive-from-nodejs-api)